# problema con fechas en r studio

Tags: r

Tengo un archivo `CSV` con estos datos

```
DATE,IUMABEDR
31 Jan 1975,11.3295
28 Feb 1975,10.6875
31 Mar 1975,10.2632
30 Apr 1975,9.9091
31 May 1975,9.9762
30 Jun 1975,10
31 Jul 1975,10.1739
31 Aug 1975,11
30 Sep 1975,11
31 Oct 1975,11.8696
30 Nov 1975,11.875
31 Dec 1975,11.4643
31 Jan 1976,10.8333
29 Feb 1976,9.625
31 Mar 1976,9.0543
```

Lo puedo leer con el código:

```
stuckey <- read.csv("resultsinteresrates.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", dec=".")
```

Pero al intentar cambiar la fecha de `str` a `date` con códigos como este entre otros:

```
stuckey$DATE<-as.Date(stuckey$DATE,"%d-%m-%Y")
```

siempre me da `NA`

```
str(stuckey)

'data.frame': 502 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ DATE    : Date, format: NA ...
 $ IUMABEDR: num  11.33 10.69 10.26 9.91 9.98 ...
```

¿Cómo podría solucionar este problema?

Comment: Sugiero cambiar el título y remover "r studio", esto es [r] en general-

Answer (score 2):

Hoa Pintarraga,

Primero que todo, recomiendo leer la documentación asociada a la función `as.Date` (`?base::as.Date`), el primer argumento es el string que quieres transformar a fecha y el segundo es el formato.

En tu caso, usaste como formato `"%d-%m-%Y"`, con esto asumes que el string de fecha viene en formato `01-02-2014` por ejemplo, lo que está incorrecto. Por lo anterior sugiero que leas http://php.net/manual/es/function.strftime.php con lo cual podrás saber como parsear la fecha según el patrón del string.

Para finalizar, **el formato que viene tu fecha es** `"%d %b %Y"` en donde:

- `%d` significa día de largo 2 (1, 2, ... 31)
- `%b` significa mes abreviado: Jan Feb ... Dec
- `%Y` significa año de largo 4, ej 2012.

Espero te ayude ;).

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda :-), voy a verlo.